# How to read text inside a tag

Tags: node.js, xpath, puppeteer, playwright

I need to scrape this page:
https://www.arabam.com/ilan/galeriden-satilik-lamborghini-gallardo-lp-560-4/mini-motors-dan-2009-gallardo-lp560-4-seramik-lift-bayi-boyasiz/14934711

If you scroll down you'll see this
[image]

I scroll down the page and then get xpath for this. This is the xpath:
//div[@id="js-hook-description"]//p/text

And this is the code

```
const results = xpathT.fromPageSource(data).findElements(rest);
    
    //console.log("The href value is:", results[0].getAttribute("href"));
    console.log(`Your full text is "${results[0].getText()}"`);
    if (results.length > 0) {
      let _results = [];
      if (path.includes("href", 0)){
          
          for (let r of results) {
              
            _results.push(r.getAttribute("href"));
          }
      }
      if (path.includes("text", 0)){
          //console.log("inside");
          //console.log(results);
          for (let r of results) {
             console.log(r.getText());
            _results.push(r.getText());
          }
```

When I simply print results it gives me this:

```
Your full text is "<p style="text-align: center;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><b><font size="5" color="#ff0000">LAMBORGHİNİ GALLARDO LP560-4</font></b></p>,<p style="text-align: center;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><b><font size="5" color="#ff0000">2009 MODEL - 38.000 KM</font></b></p>,<p style="text-align: center;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><b><font size="4">DOĞUŞ OTO <font color="#ff0000">BAYİİ</font> ÇIKIŞLI</font></b></p>,<p style="text-align: center;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><span><b><font size="4"><br/></font></b></span></p>,<p style="text-align: center;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><span><b><font size="4">AİRMATİC (LİFT)</font></b></span></p>,<p style="text-align: center;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><span><b><font size="4">SERAMİK FREN</font></b></span></p>,<p style="text-align: center;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><span><b><font size="4">GERİ GÖRÜŞ KAMERASI</font></b></span></p>,<p style="text-align: center;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><span><b><font size="4">PADDLESHİFT (F1)</font></b></span></p>,<p style="text-align: center;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><span><b><font size="4">2 BÖLGE KLİMA</font></b></span></p>,<p style="text-align: center;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><span><b><font size="4">DERİ KOLTUK</font></b></span></p>,<p style="text-align: center;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><span><b><font size="4">Bİ-ZENON FAR</font></b></span></p>,<p style="text-align: center;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><span><b><font size="4">YAĞMUR SENSÖRÜ</font></b></span></p>,<p style="text-align: center;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><span><b><font size="4">CD-USB-AUX-MP3</font></b></span></p>,<p style="text-align: center;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><span><b><font size="4"><br/></font></b></span></p>,<p style="text-align: center;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><span><b><font size="4">?</font></b></span></p>,<p style="text-align: center;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><b><font size="4">BOYA - HATA - TRAMER - HASAR KAYDI </font><font color="#ff0000"><font size="4"> </font><font size="5">YOKTUR</font></font></b></p>,<p style="text-align: center;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><b><font size="5"><br/></font></b></p>,<p style="text-align: center;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><b><font size="5">ARACIMIZIN TAMPONLARI DAHİL <font color="#ff0000">BOYASIZ</font></font></b><br/></p>,<p style="text-align: center;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><b><font size="4"><br/></font></b></p>,<p style="text-align: center;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><b><font size="4">YEDEK ANAHTARI <font color="#ff0000">MEVCUTTUR</font></font></b><br/></p>,<p style="text-align: center;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><span><b>?</b></span><br/></p>,<p style="text-align: center;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><span><b><font size="5">DETAYLI BİLGİ İÇİN LÜTFEN ARAYINIZ</font></b></span></p>,<p style="text-align: center;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><span><b><font size="5" color="#ff0000"><br/></font></b></span></p>,<p style="text-align: cente...
```

But when I call .getText() it returns undefined. What's the possible solution for this?

Comment: Hi Amna, are you using [xpath-html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xpath-html) npm package? As it is a very rarely used library I am afraid in the puppeteer-playwright topic we won't be able to help. But if you are opened to use playwright (or pptr) methods to solve your issue please give us more details about: (1) what is the purpose of the for...of loop that collects `href`s (as in the main text there are no links); (2) do you want to collect the whole text content in one bigger string (containing the whole `#js-hook-description`, or you need an array of strings with each line of the text?

Comment: @theDavidBarton the second one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`page.evaluate`](https://playwright.dev/#version=v1.2.1&path=docs%2Fapi.md&q=pageevaluatepagefunction-arg) to get the innerText property of any DOM elements. In case you need the text by paragraphs you should use the proper CSS selector for the `<p>` elements, in this case it is: `#js-hook-description > div > p`. The matching elements can be collected with the [`page.$$`](https://playwright.dev/#version=v1.2.1&path=docs%2Fapi.md&q=pageselector-1) method (it is the same as `document.querySelectorAll()` in the Page's context), then these elements can be iterated over (see a `for..of` and an `Array.map` variation below), in each iteration the `innerText` is retrieved and also a `String.trim()` is applied to clean the paragraphs from linebreaks (e.g.: `\n`).

```js
// full text content into one string
  const fullText = await page.evaluate(el => el.innerText, await page.$('#js-hook-description'))
  console.log(fullText)

// each paragraph into an array element I.
  const textArray = []
  const paragraphs = await page.$$('#js-hook-description > div > p')
  for (const p of paragraphs) {
     const actualPara = await page.evaluate(el => el.innerText.trim(), p)
     textArray.push(actualPara)
  }
  console.log(JSON.stringify(textArray))
```

An alternative solution can be done with [`page.$$eval`](https://playwright.dev/#version=v1.2.1&path=docs%2Fapi.md&q=pageevalselector-pagefunction-arg-1) and `Array.map`:

```js
// each paragraph into an array element II.
  const alternativeSolution = await page.$$eval('#js-hook-description > div > p', paragraphs => paragraphs.map(p => p.innerText.trim()))
  console.log(JSON.stringify(alternativeSolution))
```

---

Full text output:

```
LAMBORGHİNİ GALLARDO LP560-4 2009 MODEL - 38.000 KM DOĞUŞ OTO BAYİİ ÇIKIŞLI AİRMATİC (LİFT) SERAMİK FREN GERİ GÖRÜŞ KAMERASI PADDLESHİFT (F1) 2 BÖLGE KLİMA DERİ KOLTUK Bİ-ZENON FAR YAĞMUR SENSÖRÜ CD-USB-AUX-MP3 ? BOYA - HATA - TRAMER - HASAR KAYDI  YOKTUR ARACIMIZIN TAMPONLARI DAHİL BOYASIZ YEDEK ANAHTARI MEVCUTTUR ? DETAYLI BİLGİ İÇİN LÜTFEN ARAYINIZ 0533 239 22 77
```

Array output line-by-line:

```
["LAMBORGHİNİ GALLARDO LP560-4","2009 MODEL - 38.000 KM","DOĞUŞ OTO BAYİİ ÇIKIŞLI","","AİRMATİC (LİFT)","SERAMİK FREN","GERİ GÖRÜŞ KAMERASI","PADDLESHİFT (F1)","2 BÖLGE KLİMA","DERİ KOLTUK","Bİ-ZENON FAR","YAĞMUR SENSÖRÜ","CD-USB-AUX-MP3","","?","BOYA - HATA - TRAMER - HASAR KAYDI  YOKTUR","","ARACIMIZIN TAMPONLARI DAHİL BOYASIZ","","YEDEK ANAHTARI MEVCUTTUR","?","DETAYLI BİLGİ İÇİN LÜTFEN ARAYINIZ","","0533 239 22 77"]
```

Comment: Kindly share resources so I can look up the examples

Comment: For example if I use your example and replace id with class name then await page.evaluate(el => el.innerText, await page.$('.color-red4 font-semi-big bold fl ')). it gives null

Comment: The links in the answer leads to the official playwright documentation, there you will find more examples on the playwright methods. I am afraid I won't be able to share more resources than these and the examples I gave above. In your selector you should have dots between the class names like this: `$('.color-red4.font-semi-big.bold.fl')` to be valid. It returns: "1.650.000 TL".

Comment: Thank you I was unaware of that :)

Comment: Maybe helps: If you right click on an element in Chrome DevTools "Elements" tab and you select "Copy": there you are able to copy the exact selector or xpath of an element. After that you can switch to the "Console" tab and with the Chrome api you are able to test the selector's content, so you can prepare it for your puppeteer script. E.g.: `$$('.color-red4.font-semi-big.bold.fl')[0].innerText` should show the link what you expected to scrape, otherwise you need to change on the access, or you need to check if there are more elments with the same selector etc.